# Using Python property() inside a method

Tags: python, properties, decorator

Assuming you know about Python builtin property: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property

I want to re-set a object property in this way but, I need to do it inside a method to be able to pass to it some arguments, currently all the web examples of property() are defining the property outside the methods, and trying the obvious...

```
def alpha(self, beta):
  self.x = property(beta)
```

...seems not to work, I'm glad if you can show me my concept error or other alternative solutions without subclassing the code (actually my code is already over-subclassed) or using decorators (this is the solution I'll use if there is no other).

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What's `alpha`, `beta` and `x`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Properties work using the *descriptor protocol*, which only works on attributes of a *class object*. The property object has to be stored in a class attribute. You can't "override" it on a per-instance basis.

You can, of course, provide a property on the class that gets an instance attribute or falls back to some default:

```
class C(object):
    _default_x = 5
    _x = None
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x or self._default_x
    def alpha(self, beta):
        self._x = beta
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case all you need to do in your `alpha()` is `self.x = beta`. Use property when you want to implement getters and setters for an attribute, for example:

```
class Foo(object):
    @property
    def foo(self):
        return self._dblookup('foo')

    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, value):
        self._dbwrite('foo', value)
```

And then be able to do

```
f = Foo()
f.foo
f.foo = bar
```