# Setting a property inside a Python method

Tags: python, class, methods, properties

I want to set a read-only attribute inside a class method.
I have already tried this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, v):
        self._set('_v', v)

    def _set(self, attr, v):
        setattr(self, attr, v)
        setattr(Foo, attr[1:], property(lambda self: getattr(self, attr)))
```

but it is horrible. Is there another way? What I need to do is setting the property:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, v):
        self._v = v

    @ property
    def v(self):
        return self._v    

>>> f = Foo(42)
>>> f.v
42
>>> f.v = 41
AttributeError: can't set attribute ## This is what I want: a read-only attribute
```

but I need to do it inside a method. Is there another way?

Thank you,
rubik

P.S. I have already checked this post, but it does not solve my problem:
[Using Python property() inside a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302020/using-python-property-inside-a-method)

EDIT: I cannot use `property`, because I want to set it inside a method. I can use `property` only from outside:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, v):
        self._v = v
    @ property
    def v(self):
        return self._v
    ## ...OR
    def getv(self):
        return self._v
    v = property(getv)
```

And I can't do that because I don't know the property name and I have to set it dynamically. Something like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, v):
        self._set_property_from_inside('v', v)
>>> f = Foo(42)
>>> f.v
42
```

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong with your example.

Comment: Hey why someone voted me down???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've thought of what I think is a cleaner solution for implementing a pure read-only attribute, if that's all you want. It's a variant of the solution tangentstorm gave, but dispenses with the need for a `__getattr__` method altogether.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.readonly = set()

    def set_readonly(self, attr, value):
        setattr(self, attr, value)
        self.readonly.add(attr)

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        if hasattr(self, "readonly") and attr in self.readonly:
            raise AttributeError("Read only attribute: %s" % (attr,))
        object.__setattr__(self, attr, value)
```

It works like this:

```
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.x = 5
>>> f.set_readonly("y", 9)
>>> f.x, f.y
(5, 9)
>>> f.x = 7
>>> f.y = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "ro.py", line 13, in __setattr__
    raise AttributeError("Read only attribute: %s" % (name,))
AttributeError: Read only attribute: y
```

Making a read-only attribute read-write again is easy:

```
    def unset_readonly(self, attr):
        self.readonly.remove(attr)
```

In my first attempt at writing this idea I used `self.__readonly` instead of `self.readonly`, but that leads to a problem with actually setting the `__readonly` attribute, since I'd need to do un-munge the "private" attribute to check for its presence (`hasattr(self, "_Foo__readonly")`), and this is discouraged.

Comment: Thank you! I think using a set for read-only attrs is the best solution: clean and easy. Thank you for your effort! :)

Answer (score 3):

I *think* you're looking for python [descriptors](http://users.rcn.com/python/download/Descriptor.htm).

```
class MyDescriptor(object):
    def __init__(self, protected_attr_name):
        self.attr = protected_attr_name

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        return getattr(obj, self.attr)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        #setattr(obj, self.attr, value)
        raise AttributeError("Can't set attribute")

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, k, v):
        setattr(self.__class__, k, MyDescriptor("_" + k))
        setattr(self, "_" + k, v)

f = Foo("v", 42)
print f.v   # Prints 42
try:
    f.v = 32
except AttributeError:
    pass
print f.v  # Prints 42
```

Here you can do whatever you want to control access in the `__get__` and `__set__` methods. If you call obj.get_v in `__get__` and obj.set_v in `__set__`, this is very close to the actual implementation of a property, as you can see in the above link.

**Edit**: Fixed. I should have read that page better myself. Quoting:

> For objects, the machinery is in `object.__getattribute__` which transforms `b.x` into `type(b).__dict__['x'].__get__(b, type(b))`

So if you put descriptors in the `__dict__` of the instance, they'll simply get overwritten when you set that attribute to a new value.

Comment: But I can still override that attribute... :( `>>> f.v # prints 42; >>> f.v = 4; >>> f.v # prints 4`

Comment: I've fixed it now, but if you want to have different attributes on different instances of the same class, my solution will not be good enough for you, and you should go with tangentstorms solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Foo(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self, "_" + name)
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name.startswith('_'):
            self.__dict__[name] = value
        else:
            raise ValueError("%s is read only" % name)
```

Then:

```
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.x = 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 8, in __setattr__
ValueError: x is read only
>>> f._x = 5
>>> f.x
5
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I can do what I want!

Comment: Overriding __getattr__(), __setattr__() for this purpose is completely insane and not recommended. Using property() is the way to go. Such code was reasonable ten years ago and is no longer appropriate nowadays. This is very bad practice.

Comment: Perhaps, but that's what he asked how to do. :) He doesn't know what the properties are going to be called until runtime, so I suspect this is simpler than dynamically creating properties on the class at runtime. Whether he should be doing it or not is up to him. :)

Comment: Perhaps it will be a slightly less insane solution if you redirected to a new dict attribute instead. Define `self.protected = {}` in `__init__` and do `if name in self.protected: return self.protected[name]` in `__getattr__` and `if name in self.protected: raise ValueError(...)` in `__setattr__`. Then you access self.protected directly to "override" your protection.

Comment: Good point about the second dict. I sometimes also like to use an arbitrary object called self.private to stick stuff like this on. In general, I do think messing with __dict__ directly is pretty bad form.

Answer (score 1):

property() is exactly the solution here. Why shouldn't is solve your problem?
Overriding the setter an getter method allows you exactly what you want and need: full control over the property.

Please check with official documentation like

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property

in order to understand the whole story.

Comment: Do I have to use `self.__dict__[myattr] = property(myfunc)`?

Comment: Dude, read the documentation properly - especially the examples.

Comment: Dude, I have already read the documentation, and I have already said that I cannot set the property directly, because I want to create them at runtime.