# python lazy variables?  or, delayed expensive computation

Tags: python, numpy

I have a set of arrays that are very large and expensive to compute, and not all will necessarily be needed by my code on any given run.  I would like to make their declaration optional, but ideally without having to rewrite my whole code.

Example of how it is now:

```
x = function_that_generates_huge_array_slowly(0)
y = function_that_generates_huge_array_slowly(1)
```

Example of what I'd like to do:

```
x = lambda: function_that_generates_huge_array_slowly(0)
y = lambda: function_that_generates_huge_array_slowly(1)
z = x * 5 # this doesn't work because lambda is a function
      # is there something that would make this line behave like
      # z = x() * 5?
g = x * 6
```

While using lambda as above achieves one of the desired effects - computation of the array is delayed until it is needed - if you use the variable "x" more than once, it has to be computed each time.   I'd like to compute it only once.

EDIT:
After some additional searching, it looks like it is possible to do what I want (approximately) with "lazy" attributes in a class (e.g. http://code.activestate.com/recipes/131495-lazy-attributes/).  I don't suppose there's any way to do something similar without making a separate class?

EDIT2: I'm trying to implement some of the solutions, but I'm running in to an issue because I don't understand the difference between:

```
class sample(object):
    def __init__(self):
        class one(object):
            def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
                print "computing ..."
                obj.one = 1
                return 1
        self.one = one()
```

and

```
class sample(object):
    class one(object):
        def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
            print "computing ... "
            obj.one = 1
            return 1
    one = one()
```

I think some variation on these is what I'm looking for, since the expensive variables are intended to be part of a class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078726/setting-a-property-inside-a-python-method is a more useful implementation of laziness for what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first half of your problem (reusing the value) is easily solved:

```
class LazyWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.value = None
    def __call__(self):
        if self.value is None:
            self.value = self.func()
        return self.value

lazy_wrapper = LazyWrapper(lambda: function_that_generates_huge_array_slowly(0))
```

But you still have to use it as `lazy_wrapper()` not `lazy_wrapper`.

If you're going to be accessing some of the variables many times, it may be faster to use:

```
class LazyWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    def __call__(self):
        try:
            return self.value
        except AttributeError:
            self.value = self.func()
            return self.value
```

Which will make the first call slower and subsequent uses faster.

**Edit:** I see you found a similar solution that requires you to use attributes on a class. Either way requires you rewrite every lazy variable access, so just pick whichever you like.

**Edit 2:** You can also do:

```
class YourClass(object)
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    @property
    def x(self):
        try:
            return self.value
        except AttributeError:
            self.value = self.func()
            return self.value
```

If you want to access `x` as an instance attribute. No additional class is needed. If you don't want to change the class signature (by making it require `func`), you can hard code the function call into the property.

Comment: Maybe if instead of `__call__` you used a property, it would be possible to avoid `()` and it would be easier to search/replace. This depends on existing code.

Comment: I don't see how it would make any difference in search / replace? And you're just replacing `()` with something else, it seems like a subjective question which you prefer. My method is just the least code way of implementing it.

Comment: I like the second LazyWrapper... I'll give it a shot.  The solution I found had a few too many layers of abstraction for me to wrap my head around in context.

Comment: If you want to lazy load attributes of a class, just use a `property`, as shown in my edit.

Comment: Thanks, but there's a caveat: I can't set the properties within the class declaration, it has to be within a method.  Luckily, THAT question is clearly answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078726/setting-a-property-inside-a-python-method.  So, combining your suggestions with that solution, I am pretty sure I have my answer.

Answer (score 8):

Python 3.2 and greater implement an LRU algorithm in the functools module to handle simple cases of caching/memoization:

```
import functools

@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=128) #cache at most 128 items
def f(x):
    print("I'm being called with %r" % x)
    return x + 1

z = f(9) + f(9)**2
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815110/is-there-a-decorator-to-simply-cache-function-return-values

Comment: Thank you. This was hands down the simplest solution.

Answer (score 7):

Writing a class is more robust, but optimizing for simplicity (which I think you are asking for), I came up with the following solution:

```
cache = {}

def expensive_calc(factor):
    print 'calculating...'
    return [1, 2, 3] * factor

def lookup(name):
    return ( cache[name] if name in cache
        else cache.setdefault(name, expensive_calc(2)) )

print 'run one'
print lookup('x') * 2

print 'run two'
print lookup('x') * 2
```

Comment: That's not a bad idea since it is simpler, but it requires more rewriting in my code.  I'll try the above LazyWrapper first.

Comment: Gringo - I ended up using your suggestion in addition to the above (two different use cases within the same code), but agf's answer more directly answered the question I was asking.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok, but you specifically asked for a classless solution, which is why I came up with this.  Using a defaultdict is another idea I had, btw.

Answer (score 3):

You can't make a simple name, like `x`, to really evaluate lazily. A name is just an entry in a hash table (e.g. in that which `locals()` or `globals()` return). Unless you patch access methods of these system tables, you cannot attach execution of your code to simple name resolution.

But you can wrap functions in caching wrappers in different ways.
This is an OO way:

```
class CachedSlowCalculation(object):
    cache = {} # our results

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, param):
        already_known = self.cache.get(param, None)
        if already_known:
            return already_known
        value = self.func(param)
        self.cache[param] = value
        return value

calc = CachedSlowCalculation(function_that_generates_huge_array_slowly)

z = calc(1) + calc(1)**2 # only calculates things once
```

This is a classless way:

```
def cached(func):
    func.__cache = {} # we can attach attrs to objects, functions are objects
    def wrapped(param):
        cache = func.__cache
        already_known = cache.get(param, None)
        if already_known:
            return already_known
        value = func(param)
        cache[param] = value
        return value
    return wrapped

@cached
def f(x):
    print "I'm being called with %r" % x
    return x + 1

z = f(9) + f(9)**2 # see f called only once
```

In real world you'll add some logic to keep the cache to a reasonable size, possibly using a LRU algorithm.

Comment: What's an LRU algorithm?  I like your approach to the problem - it is similar to Gringo's above but maybe more elegant in some cases - but my problem is actually pretty well addressed by class attributes.  I don't actually need a global variable "x" to be lazily evaluated; I need class attributes to be lazily evaluated.  Your solution is good for the former case, though.

Comment: Out of curiosity, though... is the locals() dict/hashtable itself a class that could have an attribute overridden?  I think that would be a terrible idea, but is it possible in principle?

Comment: LRU = [Least Recently Used](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms#Least_Recently_Used): once you create or access a cache entry, you put it to the beginning of the list; the least recently used entry is thrown away if the list grows too long. Both `locals()` and `globals()` return a C-based dict with read-only method slots, no chance of overriding.

Comment: Thanks, both of those are good to know.  LRU will probably come in handy sometime soon...

Answer (score 3):

To me, it seems that the proper solution for your problem is subclassing a dict and using it.

```
class LazyDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, lazy_variables):
        self.lazy_vars = lazy_variables
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key not in self and key in self.lazy_vars:
            self[key] = self.lazy_vars[key]()
        return super().__getitem__(key)

def generate_a():
    print("generate var a lazily..")
    return "<a_large_array>"

# You can add as many variables as you want here
lazy_vars = {'a': generate_a}

lazy = LazyDict(lazy_vars)

# retrieve the variable you need from `lazy`
a = lazy['a']
print("Got a:", a)
```

And you can **actually evaluate a variable lazily** if you use `exec` to run your code. The solution is just using a custom globals.

```
your_code = "print('inside exec');print(a)"
exec(your_code, lazy)
```

If you did `your_code = open(your_file).read()`, you could actually run your code and achieve what you want. But I think the more practical approach would be the former one.