# Dropped Postgres database for django app and now manage.py won't work

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I ran into problems with makemigrations when I changed an abstract model to non-abstract and then back again -- some pk fields lost their sequence generators. I fixed it in the main database but the database generated by migrations wasn't fixed and I didn't know how to fix it, so I though I would just drop the database, delete the migrations and start again. So I did that, when I ran makemigrations, or in fact any manage.py command I get the following error. I've reverted my urls.py file to the latest commit as I thought I may have messed something up there.

I'm using Django 1.8.4, Python 3.4 and Postgres 9.4.4.0

```
$ python manage.py help
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxx/envs/concil_3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 394, in urlconf_module
    return self._urlconf_module
AttributeError: 'RegexURLResolver' object has no attribute '_urlconf_module'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is misleading. Usually it appears, when you're using Django's [contenttypes framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/contenttypes/). It happens, when `ContentType.objects.get_for_model(MyModel)` is being executed before content type record for this model is created in database. Usually it means that you're executing this code right inside one of the modules, assigning to a class member (when using [class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/) for example), etc.

When Django performs its system checks this line is getting executed and produces the misleading error. To fix it you should either avoid doing such things or wrap calls into `LazyWrapper` described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7152065/1377864) to execute code on first read of the variable. Like this:

```
# lazy content type
mymodel_content_type = LazyWrapper(lambda: ContentType.objects.get_for_model(MyModel))

# use
def myview(request):
    # ... some code
    print(mymodel_content_type) # query to db is executed here on first access and cached for subsequent accesses
    # ... some other code
```

Comment: Thanks @YaroslavAdmin, that sorted it