# Corrrect way to give a class object attributes which are only calculated when they're first used, but then saved for when referenced again?

Tags: python, class, attributes

I've created a class (which is essentially a subclassed tuple of integers) and I will be creating many instances of it at once to form a large dataset for analysis.

I'm looking to be able to query certain things about the instances, like their sum, mean, stdev, range, highest value and lowest value etc. Sometimes I will only be accessing one of these properties so would like to avoid calculating them all as attributes inside __init__. Sometimes however, I may be accessing them multiple times, and the data itself won't be changing, so I'd like to avoid repeatedly calling a method that recalculates the value each time and instead save it as an attribute once it's initially been calculated.

Ideally though, I don't want to differentiate between the initial calling of this value, and future times I do so.

I thought @properties might be the way to do this but on further reading they don't seem to fit quite right as I think they would still be calculated in __init__ and I don't need them to be set by anything other than a call to themselves. Searching around I've not found much else, but it's hard to know if I've used the right keywords as if there's a built in feature I don't know what it's called.

Here's what I've got so far (simplified), which does behave how I'd like it to.

```
from random import randint

class ListOfRandoms(tuple):
    def __new__(cls, upper_limit, count):
        data = tuple(sorted((randint(1, upper_limit) for _ in range(count)), reverse=True))
        return super().__new__(ListOfRandoms, data)

    def __init__(self, upper_limit, count):
        self._avg = None
        self._high = None
        self._low = None
        self._range = None

    def __str__(self):
        return ", ".join([str(value) for value in self])

    def avg(self):
        if not self._avg:
            self._avg = sum(self) / len(self)
        return self._avg

    def high(self):
        if not self._high:
            self._high = self[0]
        return self._high

    def low(self):
        if not self._low:
            self._low = self[len(self)-1]
        return self._low

    def range(self):
        if not self._range:
            self._range = self.high() - self.low()
        return self._range
```

And some testing to prove it behaves correctly (normally I would only get the values by calling the methods rather than the private attributes themselves).

```
test_list = ListOfRandoms(20, 6)

print(test_list)
print(test_list._range)    # starts unset
print(test_list.range())   # calculated
print(test_list._range)    # is now set
print(test_list._high)     # was set as part of range calc
print(test_list._avg)      # has not been calculated
test_list._range = 99999   # to prove it is not recalculated when called again
print(test_list.range())   # it is not
```

Output:

```
17, 13, 10, 4, 3, 1
None
16
16
17
None
99999
```

So what I'd really like to know is is there a specific built in Python feature I should be using to accomplish this sort of thing? Otherwise, if I should be taking an entirely different approach altogether, a push in the right direction would be great too. Thanks.

Comment: Probable duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151890/python-lazy-variables-or-delayed-expensive-computation, but I'll let others chime in rather than close this single-handedly.

Comment: That looks like exactly what I'm after. Never would have guessed the name but I like it. Thank you!